# Downloaded pdf automatically opens in default system pdf viewer in Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, pdf

In Chrome on Ubuntu, I selected the option to automatically open the downloaded pdf on the system default pdf viewer. Now whenever I download a pdf, it automatically pops up in a pdf viewer. I want to disable this behavior. How to do this?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Google Chrome: Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To clear the association with system viewer:

- Right click a downloaded PDF
- Uncheck `Always open with system viewer`

[image: Screenshot]

To stop Chrome automatically opening PDF after downloading:

- Open Chrome settings
- Scroll to the bottom and click `Advanced`
- Scroll to the `Downloads` tab and click `Clear` next to `Open certain file types automatically after downloading`

Comment: when the pdf is downloaded it does not appear at the bottom as you have shown. Earlier it used to. But now when I save the pdf in chrome it automatically pops up in the system viewer.

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

An update to the main answer: in later Chrome, the pdf setting at `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments` has changed:

[image]

None of the two options alone is enough to trigger the opening in the external reader, but the "Download PDF" should be enabled in order for the downloads list right-click context menu option "Always open with system viewer" to be respected.

[image]